# Destroy an excel vba User form / Excel need code password for closing

Tags: excel, vba, destructor

I got a big problem, my Excel vba code is protected by a password and always if I close excel, I have the enter the code-pw before excel close completely.

I located the problem(If I don't use this, then I don't have any problems), it is because of a User Form. My code is:

```
Set myUserForm = New FormButton
myUserForm.Show vbModeless
```

I guess I have to destroy the User Form on a way. My tries was:

```
Set myUserForm = Nothing
```

and

```
For Each uForm in UserForms
    Unload uForm
Next uForm
```

But both don't work, not sure why. Not sure if I have to work with globe variables to really set it to Nothing...

Any ideas??

Thank you :)

Comment: `For Each uForm in UserForms` will not catch those user forms created with `new`. You should try your suggested solution to keep track of those *newed* froms variables and unload them before quitting,

Comment: You have an example for me? I'm not sure what else I should try...

Comment: `Set myUserForm = New FormButton` if the name `myUserForm` has local scope, you loose any reference to the newly created form. You can try to  declaring `myUserForm` as global object and before quitting, `unload myUserForm`. another option would be to not `new` the form, but use its *default instance* directly: `c.Show vbModeless` and before quitting `unload FormButton`. These will noly help to verify your assessment that the problem is due to the need to unload some form(s), which I doubt.
`

Comment: I tried it with a global variable but this also don't work.
I also call the second code piece which unload all forms..

Any other ideas?

Comment: The form didn't unload?

Comment: They do but with same result, I get ask to enter the password, even if I close them manually by clicking the red cross in the form,  I get the same problem...

Comment: Then the problem must be somewhere else in the code. It's not about unloading that userform.

Comment: An idea how I can find it out? I can't use the debugger..
But the problem just appears if I execute 

Set myUserForm = New FormButton
myUserForm.Show vbModeless

Comment: could you try just to invoke the default instance of the form, like this: `FormButton.Show vbModeless` ?

Comment: This doesn't work I have to create first the New object or what do you mean?

Comment: I mean if `FormButton` is a normal `Userform` created in the VBA project, it has a default instance with the same name, so you can call it directly `FormButton.Show vbModeless`, no need to make a new instance of it.

Comment: Ok, this work if I use  FormButton.Show vbModeless without a new instance , I changed it in the code but I still have the same problem

Comment: I regret that I can't help further with the available information. hope someone else has faced a similar problem or has some ideas how to solve it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your engagement

Answer (score 0):

Check for 'OLE Automation' Selection in References .

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22006147

Check this Link for More Information .